# Should Service layer throw an exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soa

I don't like throwing exceptions for some reason, maybe because of the performance hit I don't know, wondering if I should re-think this issue.

Should my service layer (uses Dao's + business logic etc.) be throwing exceptions?

```
public ModelAndView createProduct(@Valid ProductForm productForm, ..) {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(...);

  if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     return mav;
  }

  // throw exception if user doesn't have permissions??
  productService.create(product, userPermissions);

}
```

So my options in the create method of the ProductService:

1. if the user doesn't have permissions, throw an exception
2. return some sort of a Response object that will have the new product Id if it was a success, along with a success/failure flag and a error collection.

Things to keep in mind:

**I may re-use this service layer in a non-web app, also in a restful web service.**

What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you mean by service and exception, but in the context you've got, I'll assume a java exception from an HTTP endpoint.

The answer is no. Services should expose errors in a general way. In the case of Restful service, errors should be propagated as HTTP status with error codes. The service shouldn't leak implementation details to consumers. It's a natural boundary.

The Consumer should handle those error situations and decide the most appropriate what to communicate. It may well choose to generate an exception.  But these exceptions are disjoint from the original issue/exception that caused the service to return an error code.

Going further I would say @yahir is right in what he says also. HTTP service would expose HTTP errors, and it may well just be using another service underneath that returns another kind of error, but its job will be to handle or map them appropriately.

Here is a good article that explains this in more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rjacobs/restful-services-and-business-exceptions

Comment: the link is broken now

Comment: Removed as that article has been purged

Comment: found an updated version of the link

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself what other options do you have, sometimes exceptions are necessary.  The only other thing you could do is return a status of failure or success and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the service layer should behave just like any other method exposed to client code. After all, that's exactly what it is.

Clients that will use it through RPC, will expect exactly this behavior.

Other cilents, such as REST, should anyway access the services layer through some other wrapping layer (e.g. `Controller` layer). One of this wrapping layer duties is transforming the response to be client-consumable.